# How do I run this .sh script?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, metasploit

Why can't I run this .sh file?  I'm root, the file has execute permissions.  What else?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this is a bash script, but you are running it with sh. 
If you run `sudo bash ./run.sh` it should work.

Comment: That returns the same error

Comment: The error you are getting is coming from line 42 of the script. Is it possible, that there is a error?

Comment: Ohhh. I see the script is running, but it is broken. Thanks!